# Sorting by Dates with multiple years

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using Excel 2016 and have multiple years within the same column. I can't seem to be able to sort it chronologically and don't know why? Help

Comment: It would help to have a bit more info and sample data. As it is we don't even know if you are sorting dates or years...

Comment: Also, please add some description of what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: This happens frequently and it is almost always happens because the dates are in **Text** format rather than true Excel dates.  Post some sample data and we can help you with the conversion.

Comment: difficult to say what kind of problem you are facing to Sort them, otherwise is easier even if the dates are in TEXT format!! Please upload the Sample data.